# Best Practice for Vertical scrolling through long collapsible submenus

Tags: website-design, web, information, page-layout, usability-engineering

We're redesigning some of our landing pages. In this case each landing page has 6-8 course categories each of which contain 3-4 courses by date, time and price.
[image: Current Layout]

Each course has a CTA button and is contained under collapsible course menu. The landing page currently opens with all menus expanded, which introduces the issue of needing to scroll down a lot to find the right course. We also believe we can organize the data better.

For this we've come up with a floating bar at the right side which, when clicked upon, scrolls to the right course category (e.g, category 4).
[image: Propose layout]

We're wondering if there's a better way to do this. Suggestions to improve the layout would also be welcome.

Comment: Hi @t0urist , I added a new response for you. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included an alternate design that shows all course options by default, but may help to remove decision fatigue and page weight by minimizing the "select" buttons. Here, a user would need to select a course first, then in a modal choose which specific class. I think it degrades to a mobile view well too. Hope this helps!

**Desktop:**

[image: Desktop view]

**Mobile:**

[image: Mobile View]

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is a **landing page** and the **conversion rate is important** and for it, you **should show the CTA buttons** instead of hiding them inside an accordion I will suggest to you 2 alternatives.

1) Showing all in open boxes and highlighting the most important.

[image]

**2) My favourite because:**

- Too many options = more choice = easy to take no choice (and leave)
- Showing options for the future you will lose the impulsive buying
- Put the focus on whats matter

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Appreciate your efforts into answering this.

Comment: @T0urist  If this answer helped you you can set as right answer clicking on check icon aside of the answer and upvoted if is useful to you. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer. Appreciate your efforts into answering this. 

For a cleaner UI, Option 2 seems viable, however we need to list all the sub-courses available for each course type. While most course types have 4-5 sub courses, some can have over 8-10 items. I regret missing out on conveying this in the OP. 

As each open box is constrained in proportions, I wonder how would we fit items in such a case?

Comment: @T0urist Could you give me some examples and show me what you tried for it? I gave you a suggestion looking for your wireframes. I would love to help you but I can't do your job. Please, complement (edit) your question with more information.